# Is "random variable" really random?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

This is a concept question. The fundamental of modern probability theory is measure theory. A probability space is just a finite measure space and a random variable is just a measurable function. We know that for a fixed function $f$, $f(x)$ is unique for each $x$. How can a function be random? In what sense do we call a measurable function "random variable"?

Comment: It's not random, but it *models* randomness.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The output of a function is uniquely determined by its input. However, for a measurable function as a random variable, we don't know the input: only after a realization can we know $x$.

Answer (score 5):

The philosophical setup is that $\Omega$ is a sample space, $\mathscr{F}$ a collection of events that could happen. A measurable $X$ is called a random variable because we are pretending that we do not know which $\omega$ will occur. I am going to flip a coin and let $X$ be the indicator of heads. I model it as $X(\omega_1) = 1$ and $X(\omega_2) = 0$ (i.e. on $\omega_1$ I get heads and $\omega_2$ I get tails)

So will I get heads or tails? The point is if you don't know what $\omega \in \Omega$ will occur, then you can't answer the question. That's why we call it random.

Comment: Thus every function is random.

Comment: @EduardoLonga What if no $\sigma$-algebra or probability measure has been specified?